# Parse.com login using magic link

Tags: parse-platform

After Parse.com have introduced new revocable session that gets destroyed when a user logs out, is it possible to build a reliable login process using "magic links", ie. a user receives an email including a link, and gets logged in in a web browser after clicking that link?

Previously, sessions in Parse were long lived and implementing a magic link login process was a matter of providing the user with his/her session token and having the client call `Parse.User.become(<sessionToken>)`.

This approach will fail with new revocable session if a user is not already signed in to the Parse server when generating and clicking a magic link, since there will not be any session to give the user that he/she can use in the call to `Parse.User.become()`.

Any clarification if this is possible to accomplish this with the new more secure type of revocable sessions in Parse, or suggestions on how to achieve this, are welcome.